# Openshift Deployment F8: Cannot access cluster for detecting mode: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException

Tags: java, kubernetes, ssl-certificate, openshift, fabric8

I am deploying sample springboot application using fabric8 maven deploy. The build fails with SSLHandshakeException.

```
F8: Cannot access cluster for detecting mode: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Failed to execute goal io.fabric8:fabric8-maven-plugin:3.1.80.redhat-000010:build (default) on project fuse-camel-sb-rest: Execution default of goal io.fabric8:fabric8-maven-plugin:3.1.80.redhat-000010:build failed: An error has occurred. sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal io.fabric8:fabric8-maven-plugin:3.1.80.redhat-000010:build (default) on project fuse-camel-sb-rest: Execution default of goal io.fabric8:fabric8-maven-plugin:3.1.80.redhat-000010:build failed: An error has occurred.
```

So, I downloaded the public certificate from the Openshift webconsole and added it to JVM using

```
C:\...\jdk.\bin>keytool -import -alias rootcert -file C:\sample\RootCert.cer -keystore cacerts
```

and got message that its successfully added to the keystore and the list command shows the certificates added.

```
    C:\...\jdk.\bin>keytool -list -keystore cacerts
Enter keystore password:
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 2 entries

rootcert, May 18, 2018, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): XX:XX:XX:..........
```

But the mvn:fabric8 deploy build still fails with the same exception.

Can someone shed some light on this issue? Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

Adding the certificates to the "cacerts" in $JAVAHOME/jre/lib/security solved the issue.

Comment: Which certificate did you add? openshift certificate or docker-registry certificate?

Comment: @jordi, openshift certificate. Log into Openshift console and download it

Answer (score 1):

Jack's solution works fine on Windows. I exported certificate from webrowser, when I was on openshift webconsole. Then I added cert to cacerts in $JAVAHOME/jre/lib/security:
 keytool -import -alias my.alias -file C:\sample\RootCert.cer -keystore cacerts

Answer (score 1):

The following works on MacOS:

The certificate to install is the one found on the browser URL bar;
On Firefox (at least) click the padlock [image: padlock icon]  to the left of the URL, then proceed down *Connection >* / *More Information* / *View Certificate* / *Details*, finally **Export...** allows you to save the certificate locally.

On the command-line, determine which JRE maven is using:

```
$ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.5.4 (1edded0938998edf8bf061f1ceb3cfdeccf443fe; 2018-06-17T19:33:14+01:00)
Maven home: /Users/.../apache-maven-3.5.4
Java version: 1.8.0_171, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.12.6", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

You will likely need to be 'root' to update the cacerts file.

```
$ sudo keytool -import -alias my-openshift-clustername -file /Users/.../downloads/my-cluster-cert.crt -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts
Password: {your password for sudo}
Enter keystore password: {JRE cacerts password, default is changeit}
... keytool prints certificate details...
Trust this certificate? [no]:  yes
Certificate was added to keystore
```

Verify that the certificate was indeed added successfully:

```
$ keytool -list -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts
Enter keystore password: changeit
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 106 entries

...other entries, in no particular order...
my-openshift-clustername, 25-Feb-2019, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): F4:17:3B:D8:E1:4E:0F:AD:16:D3:FF:0F:22:73:40:AE:A2:67:B2:AB
...other entries...
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved on Windows adding the Openshift certificate with the following:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/cacerts" -storepass changeit -alias Root -import -file openshift.der
```

The openshift.der is in BASE64.